# Django CheckboxSelectMultiple() duplicates options

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form in which there is a field called 'value' for which I want the user to be able to select one or more options:

```
class MyForm():
    class Meta:
        model = X
        fields = ['value']
        widgets = {'value': forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}
```

The problem is that, when this outputs, the options are duplicated two-fold: I see one copy of the options with square check-boxes and *another* copy of the options with circular radio select boxes. Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

See https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues/357 for previous posts on this issue, for which there is no clear solution.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this issue? Having the exact same problem.

Comment: @EduardLuca No!

Comment: I fixed the issue by upgrading django-crispy-forms to its latest version. Seemed to be a bug.